# Specifying Spring configuration file in JNLP

Tags: spring, javafx, jnlp

I have a java fx based UI which in turn calls a spring based library for its operation. I am launching this UI using the browser with a jnlp file.

I am unable to find out how to specify the applicationContext.xml for the spring based library in the JNLP. I am using a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load my context.

In my jnlp if I specify something like

```
<jar href="lib/applicationContext.xml" size="xxxx"/>
```

The loader says its not a valid jar file and quits. I am not sure how to do the bundling and specify the applicationContext such that spring library is able to pick it up.

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Thanks,
Abi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't need to specify applicationContext in your JNLP.
The `href` you have mentioned above is expecting the path of the jar file, not the xml.

Bundle the xml as part of the jar and then, somewhere in your startup code, load your spring application context using the (bundled) xml and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks and it worked...I am still confused on how it worked, because part of it was trial and error :)